# Login an Logout misundertanding

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have 2 questions:

1. Why when we don't log out from a website(or specifically a java EE login application), the next time we visit it we don't have to log in again(like Gmail,Facebook...)?
2. how can I code this in my login application(with servlet and jsp) so that when someone who logged in and didn't logged out, he doesn't have to log in when he accesses the web site again?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about java EE login application. But I think you'd want to read up on Session Cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You need save Cookie from you war module.

Save cookie.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("Your Cookie", "Some one");

cookie.setMaxAge(expiry); 
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Load from cookie

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    for (Cookie cookie : request.getCookies()) {
       if (cookie.getName().equals("Your Cookie")) {
         // if cookie equals then
externalContext.redirect("some page");
       }
    }
```

Comment: Your code makes a lot of assumptions, such as using `JSF`.

Comment: yes it is for jsf. but like this you can make it for a jsp. But for servlet need some another aritecture